# Как сделать автоматический вход в систему во время окна входа на ПК-клиенте?

Tags: delphi, winapi, клиент-сервер

Есть клиент, есть сервер, клиент посылает выбранный логин и пароль на сервер, тот выполняет вход на удаленной машине. Если это реально, подскажите как?

Comment: LogonUser + LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ? Это навскидку. Только учтите, что сервис не достучится до чего-либо, запущенного в сессии пользователя. Запуск процесса в winsta и на десктопе пользователя и то связан со сложностями.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны написать сервис, который, при получении команды из сети будет имитировать действия пользователя, а именно устанавливать фокус на окна ввода логина и пароля, и посылать нажатия клавиш.